# Share button doesn't work in android

Tags: android, listview, fragment, share

I have ListView and in its BaseAdapter I want to have popup menu that one of its items is "share" item so when the user clicks on it a share window/dialog will popup:

This is my popup menu is the BaseAdapter of the ListView:

```
mViewHolder.optionMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, mViewHolder.optionMenuButton);
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, popup.getMenu());

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                          "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (item.getTitle() == "share") {

                        if (null == mainActivity) {
                            mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
                        }
                        mainActivity.shareAction();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popup.show();//showing popup menu

        }
    });
```

And this is how I am trying to open the share window/dialog, it doesn't open the share window/dialog but the toast saying that i clicked on the "share" item of the popup menu is showing up:

```
public void shareAction() {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = "You have to check this out: " + "https://www.google.com/";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check this out");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

The ShareAction() method is in mainActivity, and the adapter is a BaseAdapter of ListView and this ListView is inside one of the MainActivity's fragments.

Also i tried this exect code of the ShareAction() method that i created and it works perfectly fine in activity that has no fragments, which is why it's weird that it doesn't work here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this code from your coding,

```
  if (null == mainActivity) {
     mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
  }
```

and match if condition like this,

```
 if (item.getTitle().equals( "share")) {
                    mainActivity.shareAction();
                    return true;
                }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I did wrong, after seeing your answer I changed this getTitle to getItemId() and checked if it equels to R.id.share which is the id of the item in my menu.xml file and it's now working as usual, TNX :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to appear share dialog

```
public void shareApp(Context context)
    {
        final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out yourAppName at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName + refercode);//If you have refer code you can give
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share with..."));
    }
```